# Insert Row into a select statement from second table if Time comes first using ROW_NUMBER PARTITION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created several different select statements for this one project due to different types of reporting, but now I have an interesting scenario, but I figured it would be far more common or maybe I'm just not using the right terminology?

My latest hurdle is that I am trying to join 2 tables together but not in the same row but in the same column....

So I have this query that Partitions the Pick Ticket Numbers based on when they were scanned...

```
WITH ticket AS
(
SELECT ticket_trail.PickT_Num
,ticket_trail.ticket_status
,ticket_trail.ID
,cast(ticket_trail.Time_stamp as DateTime)as 'time_stamped',
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ticket_trail.PickT_Num ORDER BY 
ticket_trail.time_stamp Asc) as RowNum
FROM
ticket_trail
)
SELECT 
ticket.RowNum,ticket.PickT_Num AS 'Pick Ticket'
,ticket.ID AS id1
,ticket.ticket_status as Ticket_Status
,ticket.time_stamped as start_time 
,Row2.ID id2,ISNULL(Row2.time_stamped,GetDate()) AS "End Time"
,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,ticket.time_stamped,ISNULL(Row2.time_stamped,GetDate()))
From 
ticket left join ticket AS Row2
ON 
ticket.RowNum +1 = Row2.RowNum AND ticket.PickT_Num = Row2.PickT_Num
```

Here is it's output -

```
RowNum | Pick Ticket | id1 | Ticket_Status | start_time              | id2  | End Time                | Diff
     1 | 4628750     | 65  | Yellow        | 2017-11-08 09:24:14.000 | 66   | 2017-11-08 09:24:26.000 | 0
     2 | 4628750     | 66  | Green         | 2017-11-08 09:24:26.000 | NULL | 2017-11-21 16:33:12.733 | 19149
     1 | 4647142     | 78  | Yellow        | 2017-11-08 09:28:02.000 | 79   | 2017-11-08 09:28:08.000 | 0
     2 | 4647142     | 79  | Flashing      | 2017-11-08 09:28:08.000 | 295  | 2017-11-08 14:14:10.000 | 286
     3 | 4647142     | 295 | Green         | 2017-11-08 14:14:10.000 | NULL | 2017-11-21 16:33:12.733 | 18859
     1 | 4647973     | 1   | Blue          | 2017-11-08 09:02:04.000 | 21   | 2017-11-08 09:06:05.000 | 4
     2 | 4647973     | 21  | Green         | 2017-11-08 09:06:05.000 | NULL | 2017-11-21 16:33:12.733 | 19167
     1 | 4648017     | 2   | Blue          | 2017-11-08 09:02:26.000 | 22   | 2017-11-08 09:05:56.000 | 3
     2 | 4648017     | 22  | Green         | 2017-11-08 09:05:56.000 | NULL | 2017-11-21 16:33:12.733 | 19168
     1 | 4648030     | 41  | Blue          | 2017-11-08 09:18:20.000 | 54   | 2017-11-08 09:22:39.000 | 4
     2 | 4648030     | 54  | Green         | 2017-11-08 09:22:39.000 | NULL | 2017-11-21 16:33:12.733 | 19151
```

OK so that Query works perfectly!! Yet, It doesn't tell the whole story! I need to be able to add another entry to this as a '0' `RowNum` to each `PickT_Num` from another table called `Orders_ent` that gives a time_stamp called `Printed`

So I figured it would have to be a Case statement, but I'm not sure where to start...

It can have `NULLS` in the output, But basically what I'm looking for is:

```
RowNum | Pick Ticket | id1  | Ticket_Status | start_time              | id2  | End Time                | Diff
0      | 4628750     | NULL | Printed       | 2017-11-08 09:20:14.000 | 65   | 2017-11-08 09:24:14.000 | 4
1      | 4628750     | 65   | Yellow        | 2017-11-08 09:24:14.000 | 66   | 2017-11-08 09:24:26.000 | 0
2      | 4628750     | 66   | Green         | 2017-11-08 09:24:26.000 | NULL | 2017-11-21 16:33:12.733 | 19149
```

The `Orders_ent` Table looks like this...

```
UID | Order_num | PickT_Num | Date_Created | Pick_Ticket_Printed_DATE_Time | other crap...
```

Comment: it's better to ask a question with simple and clear-enough example so that other users (who don't have much time) can follow and help you out easily. The right order of asking a question like this is firstly express your problem in a neat way with input data then show your effort (your code ...) to solve the problem. With what you asked here now I feel like that it requires us to ***translate your code and extract the problem out from there***. So it's really not easy at all. We can always easily convert problem to code but the way back is not easy in almost cases.

Comment: @KingKing Thank you for your suggestion, I will attempt to to do better in the future or even to simplify this one....But thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `UNION ALL` and `ORDER BY`

```
... -- your query is here

UNION ALL

SELECT
  0 RowNum,
  e.PickT_Num,
  NULL id1,
  'Printed' Ticket_Status,
  e.Date_Created,
  t.ID id2,
  e.Pick_Ticket_Printed_DATE_Time,
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE,e.Date_Created,ISNULL(e.Pick_Ticket_Printed_DATE_Time,GetDate()))
FROM Orders_ent e
JOIN
  (
    SELECT PickT_Num,ID
    FROM ticket
    WHERE RowNum=1
  ) t
ON e.PickT_Num=t.PickT_Num

ORDER BY 'Pick Ticket',RowNum
```

Comment: I will definitely give this a try! and thanks for your edit! Someday I will have to learn how to make it look that pretty!

Comment: I am creating this as a view, But as a view it is not accepting the `Order By` clause... Any suggestion?

Comment: But, you can use ORDER BY in your query for your view SELECT * FROM YOUR_VIEW ORDER BY ...

Comment: I found 2 articles about it https://hemantoracledba.blogspot.com/2007/01/views-with-order-by.html?m=1 https://www.google.kz/amp/s/jes.blogs.shellprompt.net/2010/02/25/views-and-order-by/amp/